# Form including check_box_tag -- params not updating a has-many-through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, parameters, has-many-through, form-for

I'm trying to implement a check_box_tag to stock a Fridge model object with  Ingredients; the two models are linked via a has-many-through relationship (FridgeIngredient model). It's worth noting that each Fridge also belongs to a User, which I worry might be causing the issue here in some manner (as this is the only difference I can see from where this code worked for me previously).

I've built a successful list of checkboxes for a has-many-through relationship previously, though it won't work on this occasion. The following form code (adapted for these models) is what worked elsewhere, but now fails to update the Fridge:

```
<%= form_for(@fridge) do |f| %>

    <!-- a debug column for testing -->
    <%= f.label :debug %>
    <%= f.text_field :debug

    <!-- the checkboxes -->
    <h2>Add ingredients to your Fridge</h2>
      <div>
          <% hidden_field_tag "fridge[ingredient_ids][]", nil %>
          <% Ingredient.all.each do |ingredient| %>
            <%= check_box_tag "fridge[ingredient_ids][]", ingredient.id, 
                @fridge.ingredient_ids.include?(ingredient.id), id: dom_id(ingredient) %>
            <%= label_tag dom_id(ingredient), ingredient.name %><br>
          <% end %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

This provides what look to me like the correct params, and the 'Debug' field updates as it should:

```
fridge: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
      debug: ''
      ingredient_ids:
      - '1'
      - '2'
    commit: Update
    controller: fridges
    action: update
    id: '2'
```

Could it be the @fridge variable is incorrect? It does seem to pick up the correct instance of the Fridge when I've tested it. It's currently:

```
@fridge = current_user.fridge #using my auth method, and unavailable to
```

However, when the form is submitted for this project, no Ingredients are added to the Fridge. The has-many-through is working as it should be, and Ingredients can be added and accessed in the Rails console.

Finally, it's worth noting the checkboxes pick up on any Ingredients existing in the Fridge added via the console (i.e. if I add steak to the Fridge via the console, this will be checked in the list of checkboxes on the page).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution - the params weren't cleared to pass. Configured the strong params in the controller and it was good to go:

```
def fridge_params
  params.require(:fridge).permit(:debug, { :ingredient_ids => [] })
end
```